# JSF form value change does not work

Tags: jsf-2, webforms, primefaces

I have a form with 4 fields (2 dates, 2 selectOne).
My Bean is SessionScoped.
When I change the values in the form once, and click on submit, the applications works fine.
But when I want to change the values in form again, nothing happens. no change nor execution.

My Form looks like:

```
<ui:define name="sidebar">
    <p:panel header="Select Values">
        <h:form id="graphform">
            <p:growl id="msg" />
            <p:panelGrid columns="1">
                <h:outputLabel for="servervalue" value="Servervalue: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{graph.servervalue }" id="servervalue">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{formconst.SERVERVALUES}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <h:outputLabel for="startdate" value="Startdate: " />
                <p:calendar disabledWeekends="false" size="10" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                    showOtherMonths="true" maxlength="10"
                    mindate="#{formconst.MINDATE }" maxdate="#{formconst.MAXDATE}"
                    showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" readOnlyInputText="true"
                    id="startdate" value="#{graph.startdate }" showOn="button"
                    required="true" />
                <h:outputLabel for="enddate" value="Enddate: " />
                <p:calendar disabledWeekends="false" size="10" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
                    showOtherMonths="true" maxlength="10"
                    mindate="#{formconst.MINDATE }" maxdate="#{formconst.MAXDATE }"
                    showButtonPanel="true" navigator="true" readOnlyInputText="true"
                    id="enddate" value="#{graph.enddate }" showOn="button"
                    required="true" />
                <h:outputLabel for="filter" value="Filter: " />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{graph.filter }" id="filter">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{formconst.GENERALFILTER}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:separator />
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="@all"
                    action="#{ graph.updateChart }" />
                <p:commandButton value="Reset" update="@all"
                    action="#{ graph.resetChart }" />
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </p:panel>

</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:form id="linechart">
        <p:lineChart value="#{graph.cartesianChartBean.chartmodel }"
            enhancedLegend="true" legendPosition="nw" xaxisAngle="50" />
    </h:form>

</ui:define>
```

The same happens when I change SessionScoped to ViewScoped or RequestScoped.
I can change the values only one time.

I use primefaces 3.2 with apache myFaces 2.0.2 on WebSphere Application Server 8.0

Best Regards Veote

Comment: Any errors in javascript console in browser (e.g. 'primefaces not defined')? What happens if you do a full submit (ajax="false" in the p:commandButton)?

Comment: there are not errors in javascript console, but the ajax="false" works. But how can I use it with ajax?

Comment: The reason could be that `update="@all"` does not work as expected. Try to update both of your forms this way `update="@form :linechart"`

Comment: Primefaces has no "@all"

Comment: Put your `<p:panel id="panelID" header="Select Values">` inside the `<h:form id="graphform">` (assign id to panel and to chart aswell). Then do `<p:commandButton value="Submit" update=":graphform:panelID,:linechart:chartID"
                    action="#{ graph.updateChart }" />` Let me know if it worked so I can put it as answer.

Comment: Thanks @ all ;) I think the version of Fallup works fine. Thank you